# sending arrays in _GET in php

Tags: php, arrays, get

php gives the ability to send arrays from the _GET.

example:

```
test.php?var1=abc&arr[0]=1&arr[3]=test
```

will output:

```
Array
(
    [var1] => abc
    [arr] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [3] => test
        )

)
```

is this consider bad coding?

Comment: completely fine and done often. just make sure you validate the values before you do anything with them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, it's usual practice. Also it's natural practice for sending selects with size greater than one.

Comment: can you tell me what you mean by `sending selects with size greater than one`?

Comment: when you create form elements select with attributes size="n" and multiple="multiple" - you can choose several options. When it goes to server it looks like selectname=val1&selectname=val2&... So, to receive values in PHP you need to name select as selectname[], and in $_GET or $_POST it would be array with key selectname.

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

That looks fine.

You can even do:

> test.php?var1=abc&arr[]=1&arr[]=test

Which would output:

```
Array
(
    [var1] => abc
    [arr] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => test
        )

)
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is a bad thing to do, and its also really bad for your websites [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization). It quickly gets really confusing if you put too much in the querystring. Keep it Simple!

Comment: No...just NO. I assume you have little to no knowledge of .htaccess rewrites. http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html just because you pass data with `$_GET` does NOT mean the data is viewable in the url. you can use htaccess to change how the url is displayed. most sites replace `&foo=bar` and `?foo=bar` with '/bar'. Additionally OP was not asking about SEO he was asking about coding practices.

Comment: The OP did not ask about htaccess rewrites. I do know a lot about htaccess rewrites, and i can also tell that your .htaccess file probaly is filled with loads of rewrites, instead of one that redirects everything to / and then parses on $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] instead. But what do i know? I have little to no knowledge of .htaccess rewrites.

Comment: OP asked about `$_GET` your reason for saying it is bad is invalid because you can use .htaacess. yes i do have rewrite rules because some of the data in the url I want to be seen for SEO purposes. Also im curious as to how you pass data if a user is clicking a dynamically generated link to go to a blog with an id without passing data in the links url.